# How to map Django TextChoices text to a choice?

Tags: python, django, enums

Suppose I have this code, inspired from [the Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/#enumeration-types) about enumeration types:

```py
class YearInSchool(models.TextChoices):
        FRESHMAN = 'FR', 'Freshman'
        SOPHOMORE = 'SO', 'Sophomore'
        JUNIOR = 'JR', 'Junior'
        SENIOR = 'SR', 'Senior'
        GRADUATE = 'GR', 'Graduate'
```

Now suppose I have the string "Sophomore".  How do I get from that to `YearInSchool.SOPHOMORE`?

The only thing I can think of is a loop:

```py
the_str = "Sophomore"
val = None
for val1, label in YearInSchool.choices:
    if label == the_str:
        val = YearInSchool(val1)
        break

assert YearInSchool.SOPHOMORE == val
```

That seems awkward.  Is there a better way?

**EDIT**: Thanks for the answers folks!  I'll try them out.  Just to provide more context, I am loading data from text files into a database, so the "Sophomore" is in a text file I've been provided that wasn't created by me.  So, I'm stretching the use case for TextChoices, but it seemed a reasonable way to tie text file input to a DB field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm affraid Django doesn't implement a similar method to `get_FOO_display` (described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display) in the doc) to achieve what you want, but I think `models.TextChoices` is not intended to be used this way.

For instance, a POST request should directly contain `YearInSchool.FRESHMAN.value` instead of `YearInSchool.FRESHMAN.label` (at least, this is the default behavior in `django.forms`), so that should not be your concern.

This being said, here is a one-liner solution which would raise a `ValueError` if `the_str` is not found:

```py
val = YearInSchool.values[YearInSchool.labels.index(the_str)]
```

That is an integer value, so you have to wrap it to get the class:

```
choice_val = YearInSchool(val)
```

And another similar solution, twice as fast:

```py
try:
    val = next(filter(lambda x: x[1] == the_str, YearInSchool.choices))[0]
except StopIteration as err:
    raise ValueError(f"{the_str} not found in {YearInSchool.labels}") from err
```

Comment: Note at least the first solution also works with `IntegerChoices`.

Comment: Note that if you want the reverse (ie. you have the values but want the display labels), you can just switch `values` and `labels` in this answer and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getattr`:

```
the_str = 'Sophomore'
try:
    val = getattr(YearInSchool, the_str.upper())
except AttributeError:
    raise AttributeError(f'{the_str.upper()} not found in {YearInSchool.names}')
assert val == YearInSchool.SOPHOMORE
```